# Can't require directive in modlule

Tags: angularjs

This code generates an error on page open

**Unknown provider: $cardProvider <- $card <- cardNumberDirective**

Where is a mistake? I see that all should works, but it is not so.

```
angular.module('card', [])
.controller('CardCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {}])

.directive('card', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      cardContainer: '@',
      width: '@',
      placeholders: '=',
      options: '=',
      messages: '=',
    },
    controller: 'CardCtrl',
    link: function (scope, element, attributes, cardCtrl) {
      // Some logic is here...

      new Card(opts);
    }
  };
}])

.directive('cardNumber', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    require: [
      '^card', // this directive can't be find
      'ngModel'
    ],
    link: function (scope, element, attributes, ctrls) {

    }
  };
}])
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

[image: HTML]

Comment: What is the structure of your HTML? With '^', angular locate the required controller by searching the element and its parents, we might need your HTML to help you.

Comment: Add HTML code as screenshot